# How to mock a object construction that is created using reflection i.e newInstance() method

Tags: mockito, easymock, powermockito

I have a piece of code below where Employee class creates object of `AppraisalCalculator` using reflection. I want to mock this `AppraisalCalculator` object using PowerMockito.

```
class AppraisalCalculator {

    public int appraisal() {
        return 300;
    }
}

class Employee {

    public int updateSalary() {

        // line 1
        AppraisalCalculator ac = 
            AppraisalCalculator.class.getConstructor().newInstance();

        return ac.appraisal();
    }
}

class TestRunner {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        AppraisalCalulator acMock=PowerMockito.mock(AppraisalCalculator.class);   
        PowerMockito
            .whenNew(AppraisalCalculator.class)
            .withNoArguments()
            .thenReturn(600);

        Employee emp = new Employee();

        int actualValue = emp.updateSalary();
        int expectedValue=600;
        Assert.equals(expectedValue,actualValue);
    }
}
```

Here, even though I have mocked the Appraisal calculator object, it still calls the real `appraisal()` method from `AppraisalCalculator`. If the actual `AppraisalCalculator` at line 1 is created using new Operator instead of `newInstance()` then this mocking works.

Can anyone explain why this is not working if the actual object is created using reflection? What can I do to mock this Object in such scenario?

Comment: Please, next time, copy actual code to SO. You have many typos and missing parts in your code. It makes it hard to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first start by rephrasing your question will fully working code.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Employee.class)
public class TestRunner {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        AppraisalCalculator acMock = PowerMockito.mock(AppraisalCalculator.class);
        PowerMockito
                .whenNew(AppraisalCalculator.class)
                .withNoArguments()
                .thenReturn(acMock);

        when(acMock.appraisal()).thenReturn(600);

        Employee emp = new Employee();

        int actualValue = emp.updateSalary();
        int expectedValue = 600;
        assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
    }
}
```

Then, the way PowerMock works is that the `PowerMockRunner` will look at each class that needs to be prepared (here `Employee`), then look for a call to the constructor we want to replace and do it. This is done at class loading. The real class bytecode calling the constructor is replaced by the one returning the mock.

The thing is that if you are using reflection, PowerMock can't know by reading the bytecode that this constructor will be called. It will only be known dynamically afterwards. So no mocking done.

If you really do need to create the class to be mocked by reflection, I would actually refactor the code a bit.

In `Employee` I would add something like

```
protected AppraisalCalculator getCalculator() {
    try {
        return AppraisalCalculator.class.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

while is a method dedicated to isolate the calculator construction.

The, just create a child class

```
    @Test
    public void testWithChildClass() {

        // Note that you don't need PowerMock anymore
        AppraisalCalculator acMock = Mockito.mock(AppraisalCalculator.class);
        when(acMock.appraisal()).thenReturn(600);

        Employee emp = new Employee() {
            @Override
            protected AppraisalCalculator getCalculator() {
                return acMock;
            }
        };

        int actualValue = emp.updateSalary();
        int expectedValue = 600;
        assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
    }
```

or a partial mock (spy)

```
    @Test
    public void test2() {

        // No PowerMock either here
        AppraisalCalculator acMock = Mockito.mock(AppraisalCalculator.class);
        when(acMock.appraisal()).thenReturn(600);

        Employee emp = spy(new Employee());
        doReturn(acMock).when(emp).getCalculator();

        int actualValue = emp.updateSalary();
        int expectedValue = 600;
        assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
    }
```